# mysql rank from results

Tags: mysql, rank

Sorry for posting another question about mysql ranking but all questions and answers which I already looked didn't help me....

I have mysql table of user points. User can have more results. My goal is to get max result from user and its rank.

```
CREATE TABLE results
(`user_id` int, `points` int);

INSERT INTO results VALUES
(1,10),
(2,20),
(3,20),
(4,30),
(4,60),
(5,5),
(1,80);
```

So upper solution would be:

```
rank | user_id | points
 1        1        80
 2        4        60
 3        3        20
 3        2        20
 4        5        5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query does the trick:

```
SET @rank=0;
SET @points=0;

SELECT @rank := IF(@points = a.points, @rank, @rank + 1) AS rank, a.user_id, @points := a.points AS points
FROM (
  SELECT user_id, MAX(points) as points
  FROM results  
  GROUP BY user_id
) a
ORDER BY a.points DESC;
```

I have also created an SQLFiddle of it so you can see that it works: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7ba2f/12

Comment: but users with id 2 and id 3 have the same result and both should have same rank...

Comment: what about if you want discriminate user 2 and 3 from other column like "goals" ?

Answer (score 0):

Use a user defined variable to produce the rank when selecting from an aggregated aliased query that calculates the maximum for each user:

```
select
    (@rank := ifnull(@rank, 0) + 1) as rank,
    user_id,
    points
from (select
    user_id,
    max(points) as points
    from results
    group by 1
    order by 2 desc) x
```

FYI, a UDV starts out life as null, hence the `ifnull()` call.